# __self__ of a new class method still refers to the previous class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, types

What I want to do seems weird, in short, I am trying to build a new class and copy instance/static/class methods from another class without doing inheritance (i.e., I only want a class with only a few methods). As I looked it up on the web, it seems people were suggesting what I did in illustration (New Class), but as I tried to test it, the class method declared in the new class seems to still point to the previous class (Old Class).

This is what I did:

```py
class OldClass(object):
    current_count = 1

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def method_class(cls):
        cls.current_count += 1

    def method_normal(self):
        return 2


# new class
class NewClass(object):
    method_class_copy = OldClass.method_class
    method_normal_copy = OldClass.method_normal
```

Checking __self__ gives the following:

```py
class_self = getattr(NewClass.method_class_copy, '__self__', None)
print(class_self)
```

it returns:

```py
<class '__main__.OldClass'>
```

but checking the instance method after being instantiated:

```py
instance_self = getattr(NewClass().method_normal_copy, '__self__', None)
print(instance_self)
```

as you can see, it still refers to the OldClass, and if I run the class method `NewClass.method_class_copy()`, the `OldClass.current_count` will increase its value the way I defined.

it returns:

```py
<__main__.NewClass object at 0x000001D8CC1AEA88>
```

- How do I construct a (new) class with the class method's __self__ actually refers to the NewClass rather than the OldClass?
- why instance method is "automatically adjusted"?

Thanks

Comment: "What I want to do seems weird, in short, I am trying to build a new class and copy instance/static/class methods from another class without doing inheritance" - that's not a sensible design. If you want to share a method implementation between two classes without having one inherit from another, put the implementation somewhere outside of the classes, such as in a helper function or a mixin.

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica,  the new class will be dynamically created from any given class object. basically, I want to replicate the whole class with selected methods in the class without running the original init and creation process. Then the new class object is then passed to other functions for other tasks.

Comment: Please be aware that copying a class is highly-nontrivial, even if you understand how classes are pieced together from their individual parts. The behaviour you are seeing are descriptors, which are the small, simple brother to metaclasses that actually power classes. If you really want to copy or even piece together a class, *ask for that as a whole*. If you just want to re-use methods in other classes, focus on the desired behaviour of the result instead of an assumed approach of copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and how [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) uses it: A `classmethod` is bound to its class by being looked up on it. Loosely speaking, the lookup `some_cls.some_classmethod` returns the method *with the `cls` parameter pre-filled to `some_class`*.

Since "normal" methods are bound to their instance by being looked up on the instance, looking them up on the class does not bind them already.

```py
>>> class Foo:
...    def some_normalmethod(self): ...
...    @classmethod
...    def some_classmethod(cls): ...
...
>>> Foo.some_classmethod
<bound method Foo.some_classmethod of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.some_normalmethod
<function __main__.Foo.some_normalmethod(self)>
```

Thus, "copying" a `classmethod` by fetching it from its class does not work as expected (it is bound to the class already), whereas "copying" a normal method does work (it is not bound to an instance).

---

In order to "copy" a `classmethod`, extract its underlying function and create a new `classmethod` from it:

```py
>>> bound_cm = Foo.some_classmethod  # bound classmethod
>>> base_cm = bound_cm.__func__      # function underlying classmethod
>>> class Bar:
...     some_classmethod = classmethod(base_cm)  # new classmethod of same function
...
>>> Bar.some_classmethod
<bound method Foo.some_classmethod of <class '__main__.Bar'>>
```

Note that this creates a "copy" of the classmethod, not the underlying function. Certain metadata, e.g. the name `Foo.some_classmethod`, still points to its origin.

If the original `classmethod` object is desired, circumventing the descriptor protocol gives direct access without binding the method.

```py
>>> Foo.__dict__['some_classmethod']
<classmethod at 0x10b6d9d00>
>>> class Qux:
...     some_classmethod = Foo.__dict__['some_classmethod']
...
>>> Qux.some_classmethod
<bound method Foo.some_classmethod of <class '__main__.Qux'>>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a detailed explanation, that really cleared up some of my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by defining the methods as class methods, only after you build the second class.

```py
class OldClass(object):
    current_count = 1

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method_class(cls):
        cls.current_count += 1
    
    def method_normal(self):
        return 2


# new class
class NewClass(object):
    method_class_copy = OldClass.method_class
    method_normal_copy = OldClass.method_normal


OldClass.method_class = classmethod(OldClass.method_class)
NewClass.method_class_copy = classmethod(NewClass.method_class_copy)
```

If you test this with

```py
class_self = getattr(OldClass.method_class, '__self__', None)
print(class_self)
instance_self = getattr(OldClass().method_normal, '__self__', None)
print(instance_self)

print()

class_self = getattr(NewClass.method_class_copy, '__self__', None)
print(class_self)
instance_self = getattr(NewClass().method_normal_copy, '__self__', None)
print(instance_self)
```

you get

```
<class '__main__.OldClass'>
<__main__.OldClass object at 0x7f1adc174ac0>

<class '__main__.NewClass'>
<__main__.NewClass object at 0x7f1adc138c70>
```

which is what you want.

**Edit**: You can also do this dynamically (use `@classmethod` in `OldClass`), by first making all class methods of the `OldClass` static with `staticmethod()`, then creating the `NewClass` and then calling `classmethod()`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I will follow the clue of using classmethod() and see if it can solve my problem.